# order union but keep distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, union

how to query a table Store(ID,Title,Company)
to get all the records where title contains "term" showing fully matched records first then partial matches.
in other words if im looking for "foo"  i wand records displayed as

- Foo and sons
- good foo
- foo bar
- football
- Herfooles

Heres what i have

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchUserInfo] 
@query nvarchar(500),
@term nvarchar(500)

(SELECT Title,Company,
1 as match
FROM Stores 
WHERE CONTAINS(Title, @query))

UNION 

(SELECT Title,Company,
0 as match
FROM Stores 
WHERE Title like '%' + @term +'%')

order by match desc
```

the problem with this query is that it returns duplicate records.
if i remove 0 as match tehn i dont know how to sort so results from CONTAINS will appear before results from LIKE.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two result sets then use `GROUP BY` to remove the duplicates and `ORDER  BY MAX(match) DESC` to place the groups returned by `CONTAINS` first

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT Title,
                Company,
                1 AS match
         FROM   Stores
         WHERE  CONTAINS(Title, @query)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Title,
                Company,
                0 AS match
         FROM   Stores
         WHERE  Title LIKE '%' + @term + '%')
SELECT Title,
       Company,
FROM   CTE
GROUP  BY Title,
          Company
ORDER  BY MAX(match) DESC
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you used UNION ALL? to me it'll work with UNION too. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Levon - It might give you the same plan in this case as it doesn't change the semantics due to the later `GROUP BY` but in general you know that nothing from the top half will be duplicated in the bottom half because of the different values of `match` so there is no point running a `DISTINCT` on those three columns across both results.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use full text search, you can do this with a single query:

```
select title, company,
       (case when MatchType like 'FULL%' then 1 else 0 end) as Match
from (select title, company,
             (case when title like concat(@query, ' %') then 'FULL START'
                   when title like concat('% ', @query) then 'FULL END'
                   when title like concat('% ', @query, ' %') then 'FULL MIDDLE'
                   when title like concat(@query, '%') then 'PARTIAL START'
                   when title like concat('%', @query) then 'PARTIAL END'
                   when title like concat('%', @query, '%') then 'PARTIAL MIDDLE'
                   else 'NONE'
              end) as MatchType
      from Stores
     ) s
where MatchType <> 'NONE'
order by MatchType
```

This may not quite give you the flexibility you want in terms of delimiters on the words.  But, it does give you more control over the nature of the matching and resulting ordering.

Comment: seems like more granular control over the results but not what i was looking for.